# Bash Script - Not returning column/variable

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am having an issue that i cant seem to figure out after a couple hours of tinkering with this. I cant seem this script to return anything to the final column.

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/Users/USER12/Desktop/url-list.txt"
log="/Users/USER12/Desktop/url-results.txt"
fmt="%-25s%-12s%-16s%-20s\n"
printf "$fmt" DOMAIN_NAME HTTP_CODE RESPONSE_TIME CONTENT_CHECK > "$log"
while read line
do
    read code time < <(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code} %{time_total}' "$line")
    curl "$line" 2>/dev/null > /Users/USER12/Desktop/domainQueryString_output.txt
    ifStatementConditional=`grep "THE CONTENT I'M LOOKING TO VERIFY" /Users/USER12/Desktop/domainQueryString_output.txt | wc -l`
    if [ $ifStatementConditional -eq 1 ] ; then 
            second_check="online"
        else 
            second_check="DOMAIN IS OFFLINE"
    fi
printf "$fmt" "$line" "$code" "$time" "$second_chance" >> "$log"
done <"$file"
```

It returns the following but nothing to the final column....

```
DOMAIN_NAME              HTTP_CODE   RESPONSE_TIME   CONTENT_CHECK       
google.com               301         1.177
```

Thanks for the help guys. The Help is Much Appreciated.

Comment: You have "$second_chance" where you should have had "$second_check".

Comment: hahah. i can only laugh at that one. much appreciated @PSkocik

Comment: No problem. People come over here with much stupider code than this. I'm literally recovering from a head injury right now and reading some of the questions here makes me feel very much not alone. :D

Answer (score 2):

You have "$second_chance" where you should have had "$second_check".
Other then that, the following is a better way to do your `if` check:

```
if grep "THE CONTENT I'M LOOKING TO VERIFY" $yourfile -q
then
  ...
else
  ...
fi
```